# What would happen if I choose a connector with current rating smaller than the actual current?

Tags: current, connector, automotive

I need a butt splice connector that can handle up to 150A, which is really hard to find. What would happen if I connect it to a 12-10AWG butt splice connector?

Other type of connectors are not desirable because this is an automotive connection.

Comment: Potentially, the splice connector melts.

Comment: What size wire (AWG #?) is carrying the 150 Amps?

Comment: the wire attached to the battery is of size 12AWG. I also find it kind of strange as the battery current rating is 160A. But i think it's because they expect the wire distance is very short, not more than 30cm

Comment: What device is powered through this wire?

Comment: It is 5 2s battery wired to 2 motors, each runs at max 75A. The connector i am looking for is used to connect the batteries together

Comment: I dont quite understand how the resistance of the connector could be so high that it heats up and melts.

Comment: "It is 5 2s battery... connect the batteries together" - what does this mean? What is the voltage and current rating of each battery, how are they connected together (series, parallel, ???) and what is the total voltage?

Comment: Do you mean 160Ah or 160A? They are different. Secondly, is the 160A a continuous or starter current rating?

Comment: The capacity of each battery is 4200mAh, max continuous discharge rate is 40C and peak discharge rate is 80C. So each battery is 7.4V, connected in series to give 37V. The current my motor is going to use is 150A

Comment: Your batteries can deliver 160A (at 40C), and You are going to use 150A. The bells are ringing, because You have no safety gap, because You start & run at full gas.

Answer (score 3):

If the wires to the battery are #12AWG (as per your comments), these can only carry 20A or so without getting significantly warmer. If you draw too much current through any conductor it will get hot.  This often leads to the plastic insulation melting off of the wires or even the wires themselves melting.  This is how fuses work.

If you need a butt-splice for #12AWG wire, make sure it is rated for at least 20A.  This way, the splice won't be any "weaker" than the wire, as far as current capacity goes...

But I think you may have a misunderstanding of your circuit.  Just because the battery is rated at 150A, doesn't mean you can (or should) pull that much from it. 150A will fry your #12 wires in no time.  There should be a 20A (or smaller) fuse at the beginning of the #12AWG circuit.

In a car, there is generally a big thick wire leading from the battery to the fuse box.  Then smaller wires come from the other sides of these fuses.  That way everything is protected.

Remember, with fuses you are protecting the wires, not the equipment!

Comment: But why does the manufacturer gives only 12AWG if the max continuous current reaches up to 160A (the peak current is 320A)? May be if the wire is short enough, the resistance won't be that high?

Comment: Also, do you know any connector in automotive application that can handle up to 150A?

Comment: @LeHoangLong Yeah, that's really weird. Lets look at the starter motor on a car for comparison: They vary a lot, but 200A is a reasonable draw. Cars generally have #2AWG or #4AWG cable feeding these motors, directly from the battery terminals (interrupted by the starter solenoid).  Could you give us a web link to the system you're trying to use?

Comment: @LeHoangLong High-current connectors are generally bolts connected to big pieces of metal.  Google "automotive power distribution block" for examples. They are used with big ring terminals that are crimped (and soldered) to the cables.

Answer (score 2):

- all connector junctions have ESR contact resistance, as well as the incremental resistance of wire with length,
- total resistance creates a voltage divider and thus a (Norton equiv.) current limiter.
- Inductive loads have a DCR that defines the peak current load possible, but limited by your poor solution with higher ESR.
- Current limit translates to loss of torque or force.
- then analyze I^2*ESR loss times Rja thermal resistance of wire junction to determine temp rise and melting of contacts. (estimates are required)

I leave you to test/verify this or do the math with typical contact resistances of your connector and wire and undefined load.

- conversely do a test and then measure the short term and long term values for contact resistance from voltage drop and current limit with temperature rise of the hot junction. Start with constant current of 10A then step to 100A, then actual load.